# How do I get the number of the most recent changeset found in my working directory?

Tags: tfs

I would like to know the command line to print the number of the most recent changeset present in my working directory.

Note, that I do not have a specific file in hand, but the working directory root.

I think we are using TFS 2010.

Comment: Please provide more detailed description on what is the results you get and whats your expecting and content of branches, your comments to Mike's answears are conflicting with how history works - either there is miscommunication or your tfs branches are misused/misconfigured. History request for folder returns recursive changesets for changed items, if specific changeset doesnt contain changes under the requested path history will not include that changeset, if history contains branching and merging the recursive (not the folder item your query) items will not show source history

Comment: The question can indeed be closed, because the suggested duplicate contains the answer, even if not accepted by OP, it is the answer for me. Using `/version:W` is the key.

Answer (score -1):

One thing to do is view history on a directory (perhaps the root of the trunk). The topmost item in the list should be the latest changeset at that level.

From command line:

```
tf history "$/MyItemSpec" /collection:http://mytfs.domain.com:8080/tfs/MyCollection /version:T /recursive /noprompt /sort:descending
```

You can pipe this to a file or what have you and the first item should be the one you want.

Comment: Could you provide the respective command line?

Comment: Is it `tf history $/MyRoot /noprompt` ?

Comment: I do it from inside visual studio. Open up Source Control explorer, right click on the trunk or folder you are trying to get the changeset  from and select 'View History'. the changeset along with its id number will be at the top of the list.

Comment: I need the command line.

Comment: Nope, this is wrong. When I try to take the history of the MyRoot I get a changeset almost two month into the past. `tf history $/Projects/540/SharpTop /noprompt` returns a changeset corresponding to the branching out of `$/Projects/540/SharpTop` from `$/Projects/SharpTop`

Comment: When I do it on one of my trunks I get what I am expecting on the first line of the output. I'm not sure what you are meaning with the branching out part. The parent branch and the child will have different chagnesets.

Comment: Even inside the Visual Studio it shows all the history, whereas I need the history up to the most recent changeset **actually found** in the working directory. For instance, if I get the version 1000, but there are 2000 changesets, then I wish to get the number 1000 and not 2000, like this method does.